# How can I see the Module window and the Call Stack windows in VS 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

The documentation said they should be under the Debug->Windows menu.  I do not have VS 2013 Professional. I am using the free version with a c# application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has to be accessed while you're debugging:

Debug > Windows > Module

Debug > Windows > Call Stack

It'll be there.